# Parse Json array without keys

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, parsing

I want to parse an array from Server but I can't obtain the array
Here is the jsonString Successfully got :

```
{
    "status":"OK",
    "message":"this is your start and end coordinates",
    "data":"{\"start\":[\"35.778763\",\"51.427360\"],\"end\":[\"35.768779, 51.415002\"]}"
}
```

I want the Double Values from data arraylist:

```
//try/catch
Log.d(TAG, "Passes here");          
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

JSONArray jData = jObject.getJSONArray("data");
Log.d(TAG, "Not PAASING HERE !!! ");

JSONArray jArrayStart = (JSONArray) jData.get(0);
JSONArray jArrayEnd =  (JSONArray) jData.get(1);

latitudeStart =  (Double) jArrayStart.get(0);
longtitudeStart = (Double) jArrayEnd.get(1);
latitudeEnd = (Double) jArrayEnd.get(0);
longtitudeEnd = (Double) jArrayEnd.get(1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to parse, is a `string`.

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "message": "this is your start and end coordinates",
    "data": "{\"start\":[\"35.778763\",\"51.427360\"],\"end\":[\"35.768779, 51.415002\"]}"
}
```

So it works like this:

```
//first, retrieve the data from the response JSON Object from the server
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String status = response.getString("status");
String message = response.getString("message");
//Note this: "data" is a string as well, but we'll have to parse that later.
String data = response.getString("data");

//get the doubles from the arrays from the "data" component.
JSONObject dataObject = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray start = dataObject.getJSONArray("start");
JSONArray end = dataObject.getJSONArray("end");

for (int i = 0; i < start.length(); i++) {
    String value = start.getString(i);
    //do something with the start String (parse to double first)
}
for (int i = 0; i < end.length(); i++) {
    String value = end.getString(i);
    //do something with end String (parse to double first)
}
```

So data is actually a `String`, but represents a `JSONObject` (which you'll have to parse), which, in its turn, contains two `JSONArrays`.

If `data` was a `JSONObject` instead of a `String`, the JSON would have looked like this:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "message": "this is your start and end coordinates",
    "data": {
        "start": [
            "35.778763",
            "51.427360"
        ],
        "end": [
            "35.768779", //note that in your example, this quote is missing (first quote on next line too)
            "51.415002"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem was the mentioned end missing qoutation and the string type of the entries

Answer (score 1):

The value of `data` is not a `JSONArray` its `JSONObject`

#### Explanation

`JSONObject` will be surrounded by `{}`

`JSONArray`  will be surrounded by `[]`

Comment: Still no success with the following Code :
'
 JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
      
      JSONObject jData = jObject.getJSONObject("data");
      
      
   JSONArray jArrayStart = jData.getJSONArray("start");
      JSONArray jArrayEnd =  jData.getJSONArray("end");

      latitudeStart =  (Double) jArrayStart.get(0);
      longtitudeStart = (Double) jArrayEnd.get(1);
      latitudeEnd = (Double) jArrayEnd.get(0);
      longtitudeEnd = (Double) jArrayEnd.get(1);'

Answer (score 0):

data is not an array, it is a json object  and therefore you can not access it the way you are doing.
If you want to fetch start array from json object "data" then use below 
 jObject.optJSONObject("data").optJSONArray("start");

same thing can be used to retrieve "end" json array.

then use optJSONObject() and/or optString() API to retrieve required value from json array.